# Failed to register Service Worker for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am having trouble registering my Service Worker for Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Angular App on localhost. My localhost server is running on https connection, i created the key and certificate over openssl for that purpose.

Getting the following error in my console of Google Chromse Browser (same error in Firefox):

```
DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:4200/assets/') with script ('https://localhost:4200/assets/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
```

even so in the network tab it looks like he gets something from the request.

[image]

But the Response is saying:

```
Failed to load response data: Connection is closed, cant dispatch pending call to Network.getResponseBody
```

i am trying to register the Service Worker here:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then(registration => {
      console.log('Service worker is active:', registration.active);

      if (Notification?.permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('permission granted');
        return this.getFCMToken();
      };
      console.log('permission undefined, default or denied');
      return this.permissionRequestFromUserDevice();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error getting service worker registration:', error);
    });
}
```

my Angular.json assets:

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
        ],
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js is stored under assets and looks like from the documentation with my credentials for my app of course:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});


const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
```

Does anyone have a clue whats wrong with my setup and can help me out?

Comment: noone can help with this issue? I tried to add the self signed certificate to the trusted certificates of my browser but it also didnt help. So i have no clue what else could cause the problem.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

had a similar issues that had me stumped for ages.

Seems like you cant use SSL in the developer serve process because firebase needs a valid SSL cert.
I was having problems with my built version outside of SSL because it was looking for localhost/firebase-sw.js instead of localhost/xxxxx/firebase-sw.js
so using your code as an example I got mine working with:

`if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(registration => {`

Note the './firebase-messaging-sw.js'is a relative path.

Then to test using SSL I had to deploy to a webserver with a valid SSL cert.

Hope that helps